# Custom Gutenberg Block: How to return plain HTML with save(), without escaping?

Tags: block-editor

I'm writing a custom Gutenberg editor block.

When saving the block I can save simple HTML elements, like in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/):

```
return wp.element.createElement('div', blockProps, 'Your block.');
```

However, I need to return some huge and complicated HTML that I cannot produce in that way. To give you an impression:

```
<div class="wrapper"><svg class="some-svg-image" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xml:space="preserve" aria-labelledby="catTitle catDesc" role="img">...<g>...<path>...</svg></div>
```

When I return this as a string, it will be escaped.

How can I prevent escaping for the HTML that I return with the `save()` method?

Comment: From the docs: _While it is possible to return a string value from save, it will be escaped. If the string includes HTML markup, the markup will be shown on the front of the site verbatim, not as the equivalent HTML node content. If you must return raw HTML from save, use `wp.element.RawHTML`. As the name implies, this is prone to cross-site scripting and therefore is discouraged in favor of a WordPress Element hierarchy whenever possible._

Comment: Arguably, recreating a complicated HTML attribute set in a React component isn't difficult - but it certainly gets a fair bit messier if you're opting for `createElement()` instead of JSX. With JSX syntax there's an almost 1-to-1 mapping of HTML attributes to component properties - the JSX equivalent to your HTML structure is nearly identical

Comment: @birgire Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @kero sure, I added it to your answer if you don't mind :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/):

> While it is possible to return a string value from save, it will be
> escaped. If the string includes HTML markup, the markup will be shown
> on the front of the site verbatim, not as the equivalent HTML node
> content. If you must return raw HTML from save, use
> `wp.element.RawHTML`. As the name implies, this is prone to cross-site
> scripting and therefore is discouraged in favor of a WordPress Element
> hierarchy whenever possible.

In addition, you can also import the SVG as a component and use it as you would use any other JSX / React, e.g. via [`svgr`](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr).

```js
return (
    <div className="wrapper">
        <svg className=".."..>
        ...
        </svg>
    </div>
);
```

would become

```js
import MyIcon from '../../assets/myicon.svg';

...

return (
    <div className="wrapper">
        <MyIcon />
    </div>
)
```

(Here I'm using [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) `<div>` instead of `...createElement('div', ..)` which is basically the same but imo a more readable syntax.)